# Prevent Elementor form submission with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, elementor

We have a simple Elementor form with one field for an email address and a submit button, for people to sign up to a newsletter.

I'm trying to add some custom validation to only allow submissions from `.co.uk`, `.gov.uk`, and `gmail.com` email addresses, and prevent submission if the input doesn't match one of those.

The validation itself works, in the sense that it displays the custom error message when appropriate, but it's not preventing submissions despite calling `e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropagation();`, and `return false;`.

Every thread I've looked at says this should work in theory but perhaps it's different with Elementor forms? Any ideas?

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    const accepted = ['.co.uk', '.gov.uk', 'gmail.com'],
      form = $('#mail_signup');

    $(form).submit(function(e) {
      $('.mail-form-invalid').remove();

      const email = $('#form-field-email').val(),
        valid = accepted.some(accepted => email.includes(accepted));

      if (!valid) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(form).after('<p class="mail-form-invalid" style="color: #f00;">Sorry, we only allow submissions from .co.uk, .gov.uk and gmail.com.</p>');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your code is correct and will prevent the `submit` event. My guess would be that the Elementor library is listening for another event to submit the form - the click of the submit button, perhaps?

Comment: You were spot on, thank you! I'll add my revised (working) code as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rory McCrossan's comment I was able to update my code to listen for the submit button click instead:

```
<script>
    (function($){
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
        
            const accepted = ['.co.uk','.gov.uk','gmail.com'],
                  form = $('#mail_signup'),
                  input = $('#form-field-email'),
                  submit = $(form).find('button[type="submit"]');
                  
            function validate(e){
                $('.mail-form-invalid').remove();
                
                const email = $(input).val(),
                      valid = accepted.some( accepted => email.includes( accepted ) );
                      
                if (!valid) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $(form).after('<p class="mail-form-invalid" style="color: #f00; margin-top: 10px;">Sorry, we only allow submissions from .co.uk, .gov.uk and gmail.com.</p>');
                    return false;
                }
            }
            
            $(submit).on('click',function(e){
               validate(e); 
            });
            
        });
        
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```